# grails - Downloading PDF getting empty file

Tags: mysql, grails, pdf, download

I'm storing some files within my mysql database. The corresponding domain class looks as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile
import grails.persistence.Entity

@Entity
class Document extends BaseClass {

    String documentReference
    CommonsMultipartFile cmfFile

    static constraints = {
        documentReference nullable: true, maxSize: 500
    }

    static mapping = {
        cmfFile sqlType: "mediumblob"
    }
}
```

I managed to successfully store different files within the table in the database. Now I want to enable the user to download any of these files using the following action:

```
def download(Document documentInstance) {
    if (documentInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    response.setContentType(documentInstance?.cmfFile?.contentType)
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${documentInstance?.cmfFile?.originalFilename}")
    response.outputStream << documentInstance?.cmfFile?.getBytes()
    response.outputStream.flush()
    return true 
}
```

My problem now is that downloading works perfectly fine with .docx, textfiles or images. However, when I'm trying to download e.g. .pdf or .zip all files are empty. I don't know what the difference is as I'm also passing on the content type.

I would be greatful for any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use Grails (2.3.11) and I store files in MySQL and it works like a charm.

The differences I can see are:

#### Domain

I use `Blob` type instead of `CommonsMultipartFile` and `type: 'blob'` instead of `sqlType: 'mediumblob'`. To set value to such a field you can use `new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byte[])`.

#### Controller

I use (adjusted to your naming):

```
response.setContentType(servletContext.getMimeType(documentInstance?.cmfFile?.originalFilename))
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=${documentInstance?.cmfFile?.originalFilename}")
response.outputStream << documentInstance?.cmfFile?.getBytes()
```

No `flush()`, no `return true`.

#### Notes

I also noticed you use quite small `maxSize` constraint. 500 B is not too much. Are you sure it's enough for your PDFs or ZIPs?

Besides, are you sure `documentInstance?.cmfFile` is not null?

Comment: Actually, I tried to adapt my solution with the `CommonsMultipartFile` to your suggestions but it didn't work. Eventually, I used `Blob` type to store the file and now it works! Thank you for the well written answer.